# Change loop conditions midway through loop iteration

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to identify a float vs int by parsing a string character by character and find the whole float or int. If I have found a '.' then I do not want this in my loop condition.

I want to do something like this:

```
do
{
    if((char) nextChar == '.')
        reachedDot = true;

    integer += (char) nextChar;
    readChar();
} while(// if(reachedDot){
        // Character.isDigit(nextChar) } 
        // else { (Character.isDigit(nextChar) || nextChar == '.')});
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you want, What do you mean by this: `If I have found a '.' then I do not want this in my loop condition. `

Comment: @user2052519 can you tell us if you only want to identify a string is float or integer? if thats is so we can recommend someother method.

Comment: The simplest thing to do in this situation is to have a `bool` variable that you "while" on, and set that variable inside your loop.  Then the logic to set it can be as complex as you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ternary operator should do the trick:

```
do
{
    if((char) nextChar == '.')
        reachedDot = true;

    integer += (char) nextChar;
    readChar();
} while (reachedDot ? Character.isDigit(nextChar) : ((Character.isDigit(nextChar) || nextChar == '.'));
```

This, of course, can be simplified using some boolean algebra, since `Character.isDigit(nextChar)` should always make the loop continue:

```
do
{
    if((char) nextChar == '.')
        reachedDot = true;

    integer += (char) nextChar;
    readChar();
} while (Character.isDigit(nextChar) || (!reachedDot && nextChar == '.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two conditions with an or:

```
} while((reachedDot && Character.isDigit(nextChar)) ||
    (!reachedDot && (Character.isDigit(nextChar) || nextChar == '.')));
```

This way, in the case of `reachedDot` being true, your first condition is checked. In the case of `reachedDot` being false, your second condition is checked.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem pretty technical for such a simple problem, so ignore mine if you feel like it's too basic.

If you are accepting an input from a Scanner, you could use `genericfooinput.hasNextInt()` to check if the user input was Int or not. If it returns true then you can continue your loop.

```
  if(myVariable.hasNextInt() == true) {
        int input = myVariable.nextInt();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with two loops.  The first loop reads digits until there are none left.  Then you look at the next character.  If it's not a dot, then you're done.  If it *is* a dot, then you run a second loop, to read digits until there are none left, then paste everything together at the end.